# There is no data source for Sqlite in VS2019 C# with EF6

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019

A WinForms application at VS 2019 (version 16.5.3) (C# ) with .NET V4.7.2 is created and all steps done same as the below link:

https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider

adding references (EF, SQLite, SQLite.EF6 and SQLite.Linq) to project and installing SQLite bundle and using the SQLiteCeToolbox of @ErikEJ and etc.

Adding the existing SQLite db under data connections in the SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox.

Clicking on the solution to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Select the EF Designer from Data.  When click on new connection there is no data source with this name (SQLite Provider (Simple for EF6 by ErikEJ)) to select.

I don’t know the reason. Your kind help is highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html install SQLite into the system. it will show up

Comment: Did you checkout the combobox content to the bottom left "Data provider:" - what can you select there?

Comment: There is nothing to select at data provider combobox except .net framework.

Comment: I have just installed everything as instructed (VS2019), and have the same problem. There is no provider listed other than:
.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server
Furthermore, Erik's screenshot on this page:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox
Shows a right-click entry to Add Entity Data Model (EDMX) to project...
I don't have that option in v4.8.735 of the Toolbox.
This is preventing me from using SQLite.
I'm thinking of looking for another database which DOES work...